# Rewrite multiple url's with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with this problem a few weeks now. In Google Search Console I get many crawl errors with the same problem: Google cannot find url's that don't even exist.

I've looked in the html-code, but the relative url's are all fine. And I'm using the /-base for all my internal links. I think the problem is my .htaccess file.

On my website nationsleaguevoetbal.nl I have two url's with different rewrites:

1. /nieuws/item
2. /wedstrijd/id/land

'land' isn't used and is only for looking nice. Now Google Search Console can't find for example:

- /wedstrijd/id/nieuws/item

It combines the two url's where it shouldn't.

My .htaccess rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^nieuws/([^/]+)$ /index.php?pagina=nieuws&item=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^wedstrijd/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php pagina=wedstrijd&id=$1&landen=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I thought the QSA would solve the problem, but the errors are coming back. Can you help me please?

Comment: I am not sure there's enough information on your question to help you answer it - can you provide a [mcve] of the issue at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^nieuws/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=nieuws&item=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^wedstrijd/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=wedstrijd&id=$1&landen=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get a '500 Internal Server Error'.

Comment: My entire website gives that error when I copy/paste it.

Comment: Yes, thanks! The website is working again. Now lets hope Google doesn't see any url-errors anymore.